# How to cast vector<T>::iterator (on the heap) as shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, shared-ptr

*I'm afraid that each existing question/answer in this area seems to be subtly different:*

I have a **`shared_ptr<vector<Point>> profile`** which is looped using an iterator. I would like to preserve a **`shared_ptr<Point>`** outside the loop for various purposes, but am struggling with the syntax. Please can you advise?

Here is a basic example:

```
shared_ptr<Point> peak;
for (vector<Point>::iterator point=profile->begin(); point!=profile->end(); point++)
{
    ...
    peak = shared_ptr<Point>(*point); // fails
    ...
}
```

*N.B. I suppose that using a plain reference/pointer to the `Point` would be simple enough, but I am trying to avoid this, particularly when the heap is involved. I also realise that I could use indexes in this case, but this would be less transferable between container classes.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Point>>>` if you want to safely pass around `shared_ptr<Point>`'s

The problem you have is that if your `shared_ptr<vector<Point>>` goes out of scope, any `shared_ptr<Point>` constructed from members of the `vector` will be pointing to invalid memory.

On the flip side, if your newly created `shared_ptr<Point>` went out of scope, you'd then be trying to deallocate memory managed by the `vector` which isn't a good thing!

Comment: Thanks. Will shared_ptr<Point> not exist until the vector itself goes out of scope?

Comment: The point about trying to deallocate the vector's memory by creating a shared_ptr to one of its elements is a good one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`*point` has type `Point`, not `Point*`.

But even if you took the address of that (via `&*point`) you couldn’t create a `shared_ptr` for it since the object’s lifetime has automatic storage, it cannot (and doesn’t need to) be managed by a `shared_ptr`.

As long as the original vector isn’t modified, getting a reference (or indeed a raw pointer) to the `Point` objects inside it is safe. Modification of the vector however may move its elements around and any references to them become invalid.

Finally I’m wondering why your vector is wrapped in a `shared_ptr`. That very rarely makes sense. Are you sure you need this?

Comment: +1 for the `shared_ptr<vector>>` - was just about to query this!

Comment: Yes, you're both right. This was an overkill and I'll remove it!